# My gulp-eslint is not working?

Tags: node.js, gulp, eslint

I am trying to use **`gulp-eslint`** to show the errors in the terminal but it's not working..!

My Project Source Code at `GitHub` : https://github.com/nicefellow1234/react-skeleton

My `gulpfile.js` :

```
"use strict";

var gulp = require('gulp');
var connect = require('gulp-connect'); // Runs a local Dev Server
var open = require('gulp-open'); // Open a URL in a Web Browser
var browserify = require('browserify'); // Bundles JS
var reactify = require('reactify'); // Transforms React JSX to JS
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream'); // Use Conventional text strams with Gulp
var concat = require('gulp-concat'); // Concatenates files
var lint = require('gulp-eslint'); // Lint JS files, including JSX

var config = {
    port: 9005,
    devBaseUrl: 'http:localhost',
    paths: {
        html: './src/*.html',
        js: './src/**/*.js',
        css : [
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css',
            'node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
        ],
        dist: './dist',
        mainJs: './src/main.js'
    }
}

gulp.task('connect', function(){
    connect.server({
        root: ['dist'],
        port: config.port,
        base: config.devBaseUrl,
        livereload: true
    });
});

gulp.task('open', ['connect'], function() {
    gulp.src(__filename)
    .pipe(open({ uri : config.devBaseUrl + ':' + config.port + '/'}))

});

gulp.task('html', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.html)
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});

gulp.task('js', function() {
    browserify(config.paths.mainJs)
    .transform(reactify)
    .bundle()
    .on('error',function() { 
        console.error(console)})
    .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/scripts'))
    .pipe(connect.reload());
});


gulp.task('css', function() {
    gulp.src(config.paths.css)
    .pipe(concat('bundle.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.paths.dist + '/css'));
});

gulp.task('lint', function() {
    return gulp
    .src(config.paths.js)
    .pipe(lint({config: 'eslint.config.json'}))
    .pipe(lint.format())
    .pipe(lint.failAfterError());
});


gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch(config.paths.html, ['html']);
    gulp.watch(config.paths.js, ['js','lint']);
});

gulp.task('default',['html','js','css','lint','open','watch']);
```

My `eslint.config.json` file :

```
{
  "ecmaFeatures": {
    "jsx": true
  },
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "jquery": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "quotes": 0,
    "no-trailing-spaces": 0,
    "eol-last": 0,
    "no-unused-vars": 0,
    "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
    "no-alert": 0,
    "no-lone-blocks": 0
  },
  "globals": {
    "jQuery": true,
    "$": true
  }
}
```

I tried to add `test: 1;` to `main.js` file which is located in `src` folder in my project and then after saving the lint task ran back again but didn't give any errors in the terminal as :

[image]

Also the page when auto reloaded so it kept loading and loading when I reload it manually so then it stopped reloading which wasn't happening before this eslint..!
So can anyone please let me know what is the problem here??

Comment: Check answer below answer, if it doesn't help, i'll delete it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason no errors are logged is because you haven't enabled any [rules](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/):

> No rules are enabled by default. The `"extends": "eslint:recommended"` property in a configuration file enables rules that report common problems.

And all the rules in your configuration [are switched off](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuring-rules):

> - `"off"` or `0` - turn the rule off
> - `"warn"` or `1` - turn the rule on as a warning (doesn’t affect exit code)
> - `"error"` or `2` - turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when triggered)

The following would enable all recommended eslint rules, plus the ones you already have in your `eslint.config.json` file:

```
"extends": "eslint:recommended",
"rules": {
  "quotes": 2,
  "no-trailing-spaces": 2,
  "eol-last": 2,
  "no-unused-vars": 2,
  "no-underscore-dangle": 2,
  "no-alert": 2,
  "no-lone-blocks": 2
},
```

Comment: Also would you please let me know why the page keeps loading in my browser then and never stops when the lint task and js runs back again after first time???

Comment: I don't understand the question. What is it you do? What does happen? If you don't give a clear description of the problem and the steps to reproduce it, I can't really help you.

Comment: I think it seems like it's working okay now : http://recordit.co/uMvd1aQORU

Comment: Well..The problem was when I would add or remove something from the JS files so my localhost page would keep loading and loading..You can take a look at the above link..!

Comment: I don't think your `lint` task could have been responsible for that. It's your `js` task that does the `connect.reload()` not your `lint` task. Probably a quirk in livereload. Wouldn't worry about it if it doesn't happen again.

Comment: Besides what can I use in alternative to the gulp and it's packages to do the tasks??? Which is more efficient to using gulp???

Comment: That's way to broad a question and not really suited for Stackoverflow.